# Angular observable depended on other observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm about to render a page where I need to

1. Get the id from the router (using this.route.params)
2. Get the product using the id in the step 1
3. Get extra data using a id in the product from step 2

Now I could solve this by doing something like this:

```
this.article$ = this.route.params.pipe(
  map(params => params['articleId']),
  switchMap(productId => this._articleService.getArticle(productId))
);

this.article$.subscribe(article => {
  this.articleFormComponents$ = this._articleService.getArticleForm(article.form.id)
    .pipe(
      map(form => JSON.parse(form) as ArticleForm)
    );
});
```

That looks messy to me.. how should I improve this?

Comment: Why not make it all part of one pipe, `this.route.params.pipe(map(params => ...), switchMap(productId => ...), switchMap(article => ...), map(form => ...))`? Do you need those intermediate observables for other things?

Comment: Just curious, @jonrsharpe, why this was a comment and not an answer so that the answer could be accepted and this wouldn't show up as an "unanswered" question?

Comment: @DeborahK I'm waiting for an answer to my question. That seems too obvious to be the solution, the OP clearly knows how to pipe, map, switchMap.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.. busy weekend ;) Yes your comment solved my brainfart.. thx! :D

Answer (score 0):

jonrsharpe is correct but to make it concrete for you, you can do this:

```
this.article$ = this.route.params.pipe(
  map(params => params['articleId']),
  switchMap(productId => this._articleService.getArticle(productId))
);

this.articleFormComponent$ = this.article$.pipe(
  switchMap(article => this._articleService.getArticleForm(article.form.id)),
  map(form => JSON.parse(form) as ArticleForm),
);
```

Make sure you subscribe to each stream to see the results.